# Email doesn't save in database when I test my springboot app with a POST request

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a basic spring-boot application (REST API), which should save contacts data in the database. When I send a POST request with a JSON content, the REST client testing tool doesn't show any errors, but the email attribute of the request is saved as a NULL value in the database.
Here is my function in the controller:

```
@Autowired
private ContactRepository contactRepository ;

@RequestMapping(value = "/contacts",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Contact save(@RequestBody Contact contact){
     return contactRepository.save(contact);
}
```

here is the entity :

```
    @Entity
    public class Contact implements Serializable
    {
      @Id 
      @GeneratedValue
      private long id;
      private String firstName;
      private String secondName;
      @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
      private Date birthDate;
      private String email;
      private String tel;
      private String photo;
```

here is the request body :

```
{
   "firstName":"test",
   "secondName":"test",
   "email":"aa@gmial.com",
   "tel":"0333433398",
   "photo":null
}
```

Here is the response that I get :

```
{
  "id": 16,
  "firstName": "test",
  "secondName": "test",
  "birthDate": null,
  "tel": "0333433398",
  "photo": null
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: need to see your table

Comment: @AmitPhaltankar Here is my table [link](https://imgur.com/a/JIDAJN2) thank you!